# Decomposition of square of an irreducible complex character

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I am looking an example of an irreducible complex character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$ such that $\chi\otimes \chi$ decomposes as symmetric square and alternating square of $\chi$, and these two components are irreducible also.

> Question 1. From the character table, I guess, there is an irreducible character of $SL_2(3)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, of degree $2$ whose values are all in $\mathbb{Z}$ (see [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/SL(2,3).html)) and its tensor square decomposes as sum of symmetric square and alternating square, with both components irreducible; is this correct?

> Question 2. Are there any other examples of finite groups in which symmetric and alternating square of an irreducible complex character are both irreducible?

> Question 3. In general, is it investigated, when symmetric square of a complex irreducible character is irreducible or when alternating square of an irreducible character is irreducible?